# how to put a floating toolbar at the top extension page action by URL

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing an extension page action that works in certain urls, I want to put a bar at the top of the page to appear whenever the user accesses the specific site, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this but it is up to your creativity. 
You can make DOM manipulations from the 'content.js' and 
style it with content.css. Create your bar with HTML and CSS. Append or prepend the HTML code to the page and add your 'content.css' to 'manifest.json'. It is very easy. You should read and watch the content in these URLs for your aim.

- [Content
  Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)
- [Fixed Header
  Tutorial](http://www.cssreset.com/creating-fixed-headers-with-css/)

Answer (score 0):

(I'm sorry about my english...).
You can't create real bar with chrome extension. You need do it with [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts/).
The best way to do this is with iframes - one for your bar and one for the site.

```
var mySite = "http://www.example.com";
chrome.tabs.onCreated(function(tab) {
    if (tab.url === mySite) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file:""});
    }
});
```

Comment: Ho, **I'm** sory about **my** english. I'm also learning english.